# Is there a specific way that tzitzit need to be attached to the garment?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis

I have always seen tzitzit attached to a garment via a hole (or two holes) through which it is "laced" through and tied.

Is this the only allowable method? Can tzitzit be attached by using a staple, or sewn into the garment using thread (without the big hole) or using Velcro or some other method?

An example, of attaching - Fold the bundle in half (like you do using the hole) with each half hanging over the corner of the garment. Use a thread or staple to attach the two half corners, and then start the twists and knots from that point.

Comment: In the case you describe with the thread, the tzitzit are still through a hole between the newly added thread and the rest of the garment. It's no different from [Chabad-style corners](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/530120/jewish/The-Garment-and-Fringes.htm), where the two holes are really close to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are clear Halachot how to attach Tzitzit and they can be found in the Kitzur at [סימן ט - הלכות ציצית](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0008_L2)  whose source is the Shulchan Aruch [סימן יא - דיני חוטי הציצית](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_2.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L2). You can also look in the Rambam in [הלכות ציצית - פרק ראשון](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01999.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L4). The primary source is in the Talmud tractate Menachot - e.g. on [Daf 41a](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01042.html#HtmpReportNum0078_L2).

It's unclear to me what you are trying to describe, but the square corner has to exist before you attach the Tzitzit. If the hole ripped all the way to the edge or the entire corner fell off, you cannot simply reconnect the Tzitzit and patch it up. (ibid)